# Problem defining a new lstlisting environment

Tags: listings, environments

I'm relatively new to Latex and having a bad time using listings inside a beamer presentation.
I know I have to use a [fragile] frame to get verbatim environment inside a frame, but for some reasons it didn't work (and I've read it prevents from using overlays, but unsure about that).

I've found a solution, which works, by defining a savebox outside the frame and using it after :

```
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{lstlistings}
blah blah blah
\end{lstlistings}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}
    \usebox\mybox
\end{frame}
```

The thing is I want to create an environment for this. Something like:

```
\begin{code}{\mybox}
blahblahblah
\end{code}
```

I tried with `\newenvironment`, but obviously it didn't work because of the way verbatim environment works (looking for the matching end environment pattern, which doesn't exists during expansion). Listings gives `\lstnewenvironment`, but the problem is that I want my box to be around the created environment, so it's not the right solution.

As I'm new, I don't really know how it works under the hood so I don't know where to start searching.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a `lstlisting` environment directly in an `lrbox`, but you can in a `\vbox` (a lower level object).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[2][]
 {\lstset{#1}\global\setbox#2\vbox\bgroup}
 {\egroup}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{\mybox}
blahblahblah
\end{code}

\begin{frame}

\usebox{\mybox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I used the optional argument just to show how it's employed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works, but the thing is you still have to `\newsavebox` every time with a different name... I saw that I can reuse the same name over and over again in the rest of my document, so the name changing part is not useful finally (except if I want to reuse the same verbatim multiple times). Is there a solution to not have to `\newsavebox`?

Comment: Nevermind, adding the `\newsavebox#2` in the beginning of the code environment seems to work...